# How to serve a MVC-view with image paths from directory?

Tags: model-view-controller, cakephp, file-handling

I'm kind of new to the whole **MVC** concept, since I just recently started developing a web site using **CakePHP** framework. Therefore I turn to you asking for how to achieve the following in a best-practice-way.

I want to be able to place a number of pictures in a directory, which then is scanned for all filenames in it. These filenames should afterwards be passed to an arbitrary view, which then loops through all filenames making `img` tags of them.

It would be nice if this could be done in a general way, so that I could reuse the code for same task but with a different directory name.

I have already tried the following two approaches. Nevertheless, non of these felt like the *best way* to do it, for some reason.

1. Create a model with `$useTable=false`.
2. Create an ordinary class and import it as a vendor.

What *is* the *best way* to achieve what I describe above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm thinking your original idea is the better one, use the Model to traverse/read/write the directory. Think of the File structure as your data source. You can pass the dirname to the model with $this->data and then let it use the [File class](http://api.cakephp.org/class/file) to retrieve what you need. This would make it portable across Controllers (with [loadModel()](http://api.cakephp.org/class/controller#method-ControllerloadModel))

Later on down the road if you move your image paths into a DB you only have to re-write the model to take that into account.

Comment: I'm glad you liked my own idea. :) However, I have a small concern regarding it. What would i call such a model, to make it reusable for many purposes (e.g. personal_photos, sponsor_logos directories), without breaking the CakePHP conventions where model names are in singular?  It's a good point that one about easy refactoring.

Comment: I would think you would want something generic, like for instance 'image'. I have an Image model in an App I'm currently working on.

Comment: That should make it! I'll try this out and mark your answer as accepted, if I don't encounter any problems. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've done the following before: create an e.g ImageManager class and pass it as an IImageManager to the constructor of your e.g ImageController instead of passing a repository.  The ImageManager could then do all the work that you mentioned.

EDIT: I did that in .net mvc and don't have experience of CakePHP, but I guess there's a place where you can register the concrete implementation of IImageManager as ImageManager so the framework would know what to pass to the controller's constructor

Comment: This indeed sounds like a nice idea. However, I'm not really sure how to implement this in CakePHP, since I'm just a cakebaker novice. Could someone give a hint if this is possible in CakePHP, and in that case how?

Answer (score 0):

I would create a [helper](http://book.cakephp.org/view/98/helpers) for this purpose.

Edit: And for trawling through the filesystem use the [`Folder`](http://api.cakephp.org/class/folder) class from within your helper.

Comment: Aha, that's an interesting suggestion; I have always thought that this is to much logic for views (and helpers) to handle, but then that might not be the case. I will think this approach over, and probably implement it if no one opposes.

Comment: I oppose. I don't think view helpers are the correct place for logic that is trawling around the file system

Comment: To add to my comment, the helper could eg. potentially create the img tags but not get the list of filenames

Comment: Okay, that confirms what I've been thinking about it -- thanks! But the question remains, where should the logic take place that scans the file system and serves file paths? And how should it be transported to the view?

Comment: Wish I could help more.  Still think my answer provides a decent place for that logic.  Then the list of filenames can be transported to the view as a list or array of strings

Comment: @David Archer: Yes, your approach is probably a very good one. The problem is that I can't really translate it into CakePHP. For example, I'm not sure how to (if even possible) handle constructor parameters for controllers. If anyone with some CakePHP experience could make this a little more cake specific it would be really great!

Comment: I was looking at the cake website, could 'components' be a way of achieving this.  haven't really looked into it but looks like it could be right. http://book.cakephp.org/view/62/Components

Comment: Thanks again, I really appreciate your share in the matter! And yes, a component might be the way to go. It feels like it's on the right level for this kind of logic and does also meet my wishes for reusability.

Comment: Also have a look at the folder class (I modified my original answer accordingly).